# Layout showing empty

Tags: android, android-layout

thanks for reading and sorry for my english.
My problem is that my  Android application should show a layout with a imageview and a textview. Intead of that it doesn't show the image and the text, it starts to run the code of that activity and launch the next activity without showing it.

**¿How could I force it to show before running the rest of the code?**

Thanks for any reply.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_inicio);        

    //Inicio de la actividad:
    //1-Obtiene la IP del PC
    Intent i;
    String IP = getIP(); 
    if(IP == null){//Si no se ha obtenido la IP se pregunta si se desea salir o reintentarlo
        i = new Intent(this,ReintentarSalir.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else{
        //2-Envia su IP al PC
        sendIP(IP);

        //3-Se pasa a la actividad en la que se pregunta si se desea enviar o recibir datos
        i = new Intent(this,EnviarRecibir.class);
        i.putExtra("IP", IP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    finish();
}
```

I want the "lay_inicio" layout to show before calling the function getIP()

Comment: Add your code...

Comment: +1 we need your code to help you

Comment: @Victor-Just show your code what u have tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like splash screen, then have a splashscreen activity. Show it for some time using thread and then launch another activity. Something like this:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;
    private final static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME = 1500;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;   

        // The thread to wait for splash screen events
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("showTheme", true);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);   
                finish();
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();        
    }

    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```